# How to override or delete existing vs code snippet

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

How to override existing built-in snippets in vs code?

I can create my own and add it in `Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/extentions/csharp/csharp.json` - for example I create a new "cw" snippet that writes `Console.WriteLine();` instead of original `System.Console.WriteLine();` but it does not override the already existing "cw" snippet. Instead it creates a second snippet with same prefix: [image: Two CW snippets shown in VSCode][Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rpbg.png).

I know that there is a way to add this setting in my .json file: `"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top"` but it only makes my own snippet above built-in ones.

Is there a way to delete original snippet or override it? Where can I find this file that contains all this standart snippets? I tried to find it in `%APPDATA%\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\csharp\snippets.`

There is also csharp.json with two weird snippets and when I try to override existing snippet by adding my own version with same prefix to this file nothing happens.

Comment: Have you looked at `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions\` to see if the out of the box extensions are located there?

Comment: @Prescott No there is just downloaded extentions and nothing with snippets unfortunately